# Voice over - resume dictation

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover

I have a page where the elements are added to the view in below order:

---

Self.view

- title (Label)
- close (Button)
- back (Button)
- next (Button)
- scrollview

---

The Voice Over dictation is set to start from the title, close, next, back, and then to the subviews of scrollview. It works as expected unless until I leave to another page and come back. Whenever this page is loaded again from another view, it starts dictating from `title` all over again, though the page's UI stays at where it was last left at.

The scrollview is set to scroll in horizontal direction and it has 10 subviews(questions) to mimic a pagination effect. On 4th and 9th pages, I have option to where it needs to present another controller A. When dismissing from the controller `A`, the Voice Over starts dictating from `title` instead of resuming from the last element active i.e the 4th page's question or its options. This is a [mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnyDF.png) of the placement of UI elements where I have difficulty fixing Voice Over elements order.

---

```
horizontalScroller.accessibilityElements = [firstQuestion, secondQuestion, thirdQuestion, fourthQuestion, fifthQuestion, sixthQuestion, seventhQuestion, eigthQuestion, ninthQuestion, finalQuestion]
view.accessibilityElements = [titlelabelLabel, closebuttonButton, nextButton, backButton, horizontalScroller]
```

---

I assume it is because Voice Over is designed to start all over from the beginning each time it loads a page. But, in this case it would be quite confusing to a visually impaired user to go over same question, IMO. Any help in tweaking this to resume where it was last at, would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your view appears you can check if VoiceOver is running with:

```
UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning
```

If VoiceOver is running, you can use the following to make VoiceOver move to `targetView`:

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: targetView)
```

And if that doesn’t work:

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: targetView)
```

Edit: posting the notifications after a delay is needed in some cases.

Comment: What happened? Try `viewDidAppear`. Is your target view added after these calls? It needs to already be in the view hierarchy

Comment: Post the `UIAccessibility` notification only on `viewDidAppear` or else the voice over will ignore it and start from the first view again when the screen changes.

Comment: You may also try posting the notification after a 0.5 second delay.